# Django | Annotate objects to query

Tags: python, sql, django, django-queryset, annotate

I am currently struggling to figure out how to deal with the following problem:

Imagine I got this two models:

```
class author(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(mac_length=50)
     ...
```

and

```
class book(models.Model):
     author = models.ForeignKey('author', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     ...
```

Now I want to create a view which list all authors with all their book's.
This could look something like this:

*Joanne K. Rowling*:

- Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone
- ...

*J. R. R. Tolkien*:

- The Hobbit
- ...

**Question:**
How should the Django Query look like to access the Books in the template? `

```
authors = authors.objects.all()
```

This gives me the set for the authors, but not their belonging books.
Is there a way to annotate or aggregate Dict's to the Queryset?
I feel like this beeing Rookie stuff, but it would still be nice if you could help me out.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for something like :

`authors = authors.objects.all().prefetch_related('book_set')`

then access them this way:

```
for author in authors:
    books = author.book_set.all()
```

Comment: please add explanation and/or relevant documentation as well.